# Drop down selected value is undefined on drop down change event in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a drop down in MVC application Drop down has two values. I got both value and text in html(from firebug). But I am facing a strange issue.
I am getting the drop down selected value undefined and selected text an empty string on drop down change event.

My Code is like:

```
$('#mydropdownid').on("change",function(){

    var selectedValue=$('#mydropdownid option:selected').val();
    var selectedText=$('#mydropdownid option:selected').text();

});
```

I have also tried with
$('#mydropdownid').find('option:selected').text();

but the result is same.What should be the issue ??

Comment: your code has error `var selectedValue=$('#mydropdownid option:selected).val();`  in this line there is end quote for selector . it may be a typo. if it is not then upadte your code.

Comment: Are you changing the dropdown contents from clicking it normally? or via some javascript or data-binding?

Comment: just clicking it normally from UI @owen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$(this)` and get the `.val()`, and `.text()` like below:

```js
$('#mydropdownid').on("change", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mydropdownid">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

By using `$(this)`, you can change the id without having to go through all your code and updating the id everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val()` directly on drop down like this:

```
$('#mydropdownid').on("change",function(){

    var selectedValue=$('#mydropdownid').val();
    var selectedText=$('#mydropdownid option:selected').text();

});
```

The `.text()` should work just like you have it. [See here.](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/29qpncpn/1/)